# UIViewController rendering behind the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController which has a table view and a date picker view. I push this view from another view using the navigation controller but this view gets rendered behind the navigation bar. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. All other views in my app render correctly. This is the only UIViewController in my app all other are UITableViewController.

The following is the screenshot.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out why the view was rendering behind the navigation bar. I had set the translucent property to yes on the navigation bar in the app delegate. This was causing the view to render behind the navigation bar. Setting it to no solved the issue.